# Bootstrap 3.0 and nicescroll plugin showed under the navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nicescroll

I'm using ***Bootstrap 3.0 with nicescroll plugin***, in my project i use **navbar-fixed-top** and i leave **50px padding top** so everything works good, the problem is nicescroll plugin showed under the navbar like the image below:

[image]

instead being like this :

[image]

Comment: I tried this  http://fiddle.jshell.net/Bt8AE/1/show/ Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/Bt8AE/1/ . But still not getting. gave padding top and margin top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding **zindex:"10000"** to **nicescroll** will make it above all the elements of the page and will solve the problem, hope anyone have problem like this to get solved.